# C# Code Contracts: How to validate parameters of interfacemethod defined in other assembly?

Tags: c#, parameters, code-contracts

I have a situation I don't know how it's supposed to be solved.
According to the [user manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) section 3, a contractmethod, i.e. `Require` or `Ensure`, is not allowed in overriding methods/properties or interface implementations. The contract methods should be declared in the root virtual/abstract method and since you can't declare code in an abstract method, you have to work with the `ContractClassAttribute` and `ContractClassForAttribute`. The same goes for contractmethods for interfacemembers(and their implementations).

But what if I want to use an interface I haven't created myself? For example `IList<T>` doesn't implement these contract methods, but I can't set the `ContractClassAttribute` on it either. How should I do parametervalidation in for example the implementation of `IList<T>.this[int]`? The following solutions aren't allowed:

```
T IList<T>.this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Requires(i >= 0);//not allowed

        if (i < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        Contract.EndContractBlock();//also not allowed
        ...
    }
}
```

Are the legacy if-then-throw statements without `EndContractBlock` the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, *IList<T>* already specifies that precondition. I just tried it to be sure: *"Precondition failed: index >= 0"*.

Furthermore, as I understand it, post conditions are allowed, only preconditions aren't.

If, you would still like to add other preconditions, I believe this answers your question:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/codecontracts/thread/af403bbc-ca4e-4546-8b7a-3fb3dba4bb4a

It basicly comes down to the fact that you are not meant to do so, as that would defy the purpose of code contracts.

Comment: Ok thnx. I didn't come across the distinction between pre- and postconditions in the user manual, but it makes sense that only preconditions aren't allowed. So I agree I shouldn't add preconditions :P

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't add preconditions is the same reason you can't do this:

```
interface IInterface
{
    void Foo(Parent x);
}

class Implementation : IInterface
{
    void Foo(Child x);
}
```

It's related to (co-/contra-)variance — method parameters are contravariant, meaning the type you accept has to be "at least as big/liberal" as the type that the interface specifies.

Adding more pre-conditions is making the type smaller/stricter, in the same way that accepting a subclass of the type would be (like in the example above).* You can't do this for obvious reasons — a class which implements the interface might not work when passed the correct arguments! If you flipped `Parent` & `Child` it would be ok.

With method return types it's the other way around: they're covariant, meaning you have to be "at least as small/strict" as the type the interface specifies. This is why you can add post-conditions, because you're making the type "smaller/stricter". It's the same reason why this works:

```
interface IInterface
{
    Parent Foo();
}

class Implementation : IInterface
{
    Child Foo();
}
```

* (This actually raises the question of whether you should be able to *remove* pre-conditions from implementing classes. This would be an interesting feature.)

Comment: Steven had already convinced me, but thanks anywayz. About the removability of preconditions, I would vote against that. If you would want an interface with weaker preconditions, you essentially change the entire contract of the interface. So I'd suggest creating a new interface, instead of the first interface having two separate purposes.